How can I disable the Yellow Highlighting of @ in Blazor Visual Studio?
How can I disable the Yellow Highlighting of @ in Blazor Visual Studio?  See below Screenshot.  I believe this Highlighting turned ON with the latest Visual Studio update.

Thank you for your help and advice. I don't know what else I can write to add value.


How can I disable the Yellow Highlighting of @ in Blazor Visual Studio?

Go to Tools, Options and then Environment, Fonts and Colors.
Keep the settings selection on "Text Editor" and find "Razor C# Transition".
You can pick foregroud/background colors there.

I believe this Highlighting turned ON with the latest Visual Studio update.

It was always highlighted as a "Razor Directive". The "Transition" element might be new, I don't know.
